# What can trigger a SIGPWR signal that interrupts a 'sendmsg' system call?

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, tcp, strace, system-calls

On a RHEL 6 host, I have a Cassandra server listening for TCP connections on localhost. In parallel, I have a client application that sends it requests. The client (C# Mono) uses [`sendmsg`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sendmsg) to send the serialized bytes.

I consistently see the `sendmsg` return without having sent all requested bytes. I used `strace` to try to debug this

```
sudo strace -p<pid> -s 100 -f -tt &> tmp.out
```

and saw (filtered sample for a thread tid `47605`)

```
[pid 47605] 16:32:13.388307 sendmsg(8, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(2)=[{"\4\0\0\1\n\0\0]x\0\20\2545\250\260\34\26152:{i\261\204\266\3759\0\n\5\0\2\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\1\0\0]Q0_1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_10_11_12_13_14_15_16_17_18_19_20_21_"..., 16384}, {"3490_3491_3492_3493_3494_3495_3496_3497_3498_3499_3500_3501_3502_3503_3504_3505_3506_3507_3508_3509_"..., 7553}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0 <unfinished ...>
[pid 46142] 16:32:13.413922 tgkill(46142, 47605, SIGPWR) = 0
[pid 47605] 16:32:13.414024 <... sendmsg resumed> ) = 16384
[pid 47605] 16:32:13.414094 --- SIGPWR (Power failure) @ 0 (0) ---
[pid 47605] 16:32:13.414191 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [XCPU],  <unfinished ...>
[pid 47605] 16:32:13.414242 <... rt_sigprocmask resumed> NULL, 8) = 0
[pid 47605] 16:32:13.414304 rt_sigsuspend(~[XCPU RTMIN RT_1] <unfinished ...>
[pid 46142] 16:32:13.418930 tgkill(46142, 47605, SIGXCPU) = 0
[pid 47605] 16:32:13.419057 <... rt_sigsuspend resumed> ) = ? ERESTARTNOHAND (To be restarted)
[pid 47605] 16:32:13.419143 --- SIGXCPU (CPU time limit exceeded) @ 0 (0) ---
[pid 47605] 16:32:13.419236 rt_sigreturn(0x30 <unfinished ...>
[pid 47605] 16:32:13.419306 <... rt_sigreturn resumed> ) = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
[pid 47605] 16:32:13.419360 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [XCPU],  <unfinished ...>
[pid 47605] 16:32:13.419431 <... rt_sigprocmask resumed> NULL, 8) = 0
[pid 47605] 16:32:13.419481 rt_sigreturn(0xffffffff <unfinished ...>
[pid 47605] 16:32:13.419562 <... rt_sigreturn resumed> ) = 16384
```

This seems to indicate that thread with tid `46142` used `tgkill` to send a SIGPWR signal to thread with tid `47605` which was in the process of sending bytes with `sendmsg`. This somehow interrupted it and it only ended up sending 16384 of the 23937 bytes requested.

I tried to see if the thread with tid `46142` was doing anything that could explain the cause of the `tgkill`, but all I see is

```
[pid 46142] 16:32:13.370983 futex(0x34af8d0, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 46142] 16:32:13.371061 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
[pid 46142] 16:32:13.371169 futex(0x34af8d0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid 46142] 16:32:13.371221 <... futex resumed> ) = 0
[pid 46142] 16:32:13.377014 brk(0x3d45000 <unfinished ...>
[pid 46142] 16:32:13.377254 <... brk resumed> ) = 0x3d45000
[pid 46142] 16:32:13.378971 mmap(0x40696000, 65536, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_32BIT, -1, 0) = 0x40696000
[pid 46142] 16:32:13.381868 futex(0x7feb0000b88c, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x7feb0000b888, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
[pid 46142] 16:32:13.413922 tgkill(46142, 47605, SIGPWR) = 0
[pid 46142] 16:32:13.413992 tgkill(46142, 47599, SIGPWR <unfinished ...>
[pid 46142] 16:32:13.414221 <... tgkill resumed> ) = 0
[pid 46142] 16:32:13.414267 tgkill(46142, 46146, SIGPWR <unfinished ...>
[pid 46142] 16:32:13.414437 <... tgkill resumed> ) = 0
[pid 46142] 16:32:13.414601 futex(0x1b1e320, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 46142] 16:32:13.414718 <... futex resumed> ) = 0
[pid 46142] 16:32:13.414767 mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feb19800000
```

which I can't make sense of in the context of the network system call.

What could cause a thread to send a SIGPWR signal?

---

I'm unsure if this is relevant, but I'm using a socket send buffer size of 4096 and the loopback interface's MTU size is set to 16436. I can consistently reproduce the partial `sendmsg` with these sizes. If, however, I double the MTU size, the problem goes away. Similarly, if I set my socket's send buffer size to something much larger like 24000, I can no longer reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Everything that threads do is just part of the program's *own* code, or of some library it uses. So the answer to "What could cause a thread to send a SIGPWR signal?" is going to vary from program to program.

In your case, it's the **Mono runtime** which uses these internally. From what I could find out, SIGPWR and SIGXCPU are used to [trigger the garbage collector](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-devel-list/2004-December/009560.html).

Comment: Thank you for the find. That sounds correct for the version of Mono I'm using. Is `sendmsg` special in the way the executing thread handles a signal? Its man page didn't seem to address the scenario where it's already started sending. (Also, any idea why the MTU would make a difference?)